# Upload a sound file using browser address bar

Tags: json, post

Please clarify for me:

1. Does web browser support only `GET` method, not `POST`?
2. Is there any way to upload the sound file using `POST` request in address bar (without using CURL, or any add-ons)?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers only allow you to make GET requests though the address bar UI. There is no way to trigger a POST request using it.

In theory, you could encode audio as a text string (e.g. using base64) and pass that through the URL in a GET request … but that isn't really in the spirit of HTTP and you will run into URL length limits for all but the smallest audio files.